# Git checkout-index does not work in git hooks

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

In `.git/hooks`, I enable `pre-commit`. I want to extract staged files into another dir. Here is my command.

```
git diff --cached --name-only | grep -E ".*\.(kt|java)" | git --git-dir=.git --work-tree=staged-dir checkout-index -f -q --stdin
```

As you see, I filter java and kotlin files. However above code does not work for me in `pre-commit`. But if I execute above command in terminal, staged files extracted into `staged-dir` directory.

## EDIT

When I remove `checkout-index`, there is some output.

```
git diff --cached --name-only | grep -E ".*\.(kt|java)"
```

> project/A.kt
>
> project/B.java

## EDIT For Project structure

```
rootProject
  |---.git
  |---staged-dir
```

Comment: Do you using Windows? If yes, do you using Comodo antivirus?

Comment: You might want to add an echo statement to check if the hook is actually being executed?

Comment: Yes it's executed.

Comment: @bimlas I am using MacOS.

Comment: It's worth checking that `$(pwd)` is where you expect it to be. If not, the arguments to `--git-dir` and `--work-tree`, which are relative to the current working directory, will be wrong. However, pre-commit hooks are (I think) supposed to run in the top level of the work-tree, so this *should* be correct...

Comment: Yes I have checked pwd and it's root path. So I can not find why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make the file executable and add a proper shebang (I.e: **!# /bin/bash**)

From [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks):

> To enable a hook script, put a file in the hooks   subdirectory of your Git directory that is named  appropriately and is executable.

Comment: Yes I have make it executable. `chmod +x`

Comment: Does it have a proper shebang (**#! /bin/bash**)?

Comment: I use ` #!/usr/bin/env bash` .

Answer (score 0):

If `core.hooksPath` is set in your `~/.gitconfig`, it's disabling the per-repository hooks. Try to comment out this configuration and check that the hook is executed by adding these lines to it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'OK' > "`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`"/pre-commit-hook-executed
```

It has to create a file in the top directory of the repository. If it's not exist after commiting (or at least when the commit message editor opens), then the hook is not executed.

For details see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corehooksPath

Comment: The hook is actually executed. I have echo some word in `pre-commit`.